# Array Manipulation - randomly choosing elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I have an array of length `N`. I want to choose `n` positions randomly, make them zero and then add the existing elements to the next non-zero element.

For example, suppose `r = (r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)`, `N = 5`. Let `n = 2`. And the randomly picked positions are 3rd and 4th. Then I want to transform `r` to 
`r_new = (r1, r2, 0, 0, r3+r4+r5)`.

Instead if the randomly selected positions were `1` and `3`, then I want to have
`r_new = (0, r1 + r2, 0, r3+r4, r5)`.

I am coding in MATLAB. Here is my current code.

```
u   = randperm(T);
ind = sort(u(1:n(i)));
tmp = r(ind);
r(ind) = 0;

x = find( r );
```

I am not necessarily looking for MATLAB code. Pseudocode would be helpful enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming *the last position can never be selected*, otherwise the intended behaviour is undefined. So you randomly select `n` positions uniformly distributed from `1` up to `N-1` (not up to `N`).

Here's one approach:

1. Select `n` distinct random positions from `1` to `N-1`, and sort them. Call the resulting vector of positions `pos`. This can be easily done with [`randperm`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) and [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).
2. For each value in `pos`, say `p`, accumulate `r(p)` into `r(p+1)`, and set `r(p)` to zero. This is done with a [`for`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop.

In step 2, if position `p+1` happens to belong to `pos` too, the accumulated value will be moved further to the right in a subsequent iteration. This works because `pos` has been sorted, so the randomly selected positions are processed from left to right.

```
r = [3 5 4 3 7 2 8]; %// data
n = 2; %// number of positions
pos = sort(randperm(numel(r)-1,n)); %// randomly select positions, and sort them
for p = pos
    r([p p+1]) = [0 r(p)+r(p+1)]; %// process position p
end
```

Comment: `randsample` requires the statistics toolbox. For a vanilla MATLAB sampling you could use something like `idx = zeros(n, 1); while length(unique(idx)) < n; idx = sort(randi(numel(r)-1, [1 n])); end` to ensure you get unique integer values.

Comment: @excaza ... or you could use `randperm`: `pos = randperm(numel(r)-1,n)`. Good idea, thanks! I'll change that to avoid the Statistics toolbox

Comment: oops, duh, that's a much cleaner option

Comment: I am getting `??? Error using ==> horzcat  CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.` error

Comment: @deb With what data exactly?

Comment: @LuisMendo never mind. My guess is it is because I am using Matlab 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming N, n and r are already generated, then we select random indexes:

```
inds = randi(N,n,1);
```

Then to achieve the desired results you can loop as follows:

```
inds = sort(inds);

for ii=1:numel(inds)
    if(inds(ii)<N)
        r(inds(ii)+1)=r(inds(ii)+1) +r(inds(ii));
        r(inds)=0;
    else
        r(inds)=0;
    end
end
```

This will create the desired outcome of adding the values to the next index that wasn't selected to be set to 0.

Note I had to assume an edge case where if the last index is set to 0, then its value is not added to anything.

Comment: What happens if `randi` returns the same integer multiple times?

Comment: The result is the same as the case in which you used only the unique subset of the selected indexes. The main point of the questions seemed to me about the desired changes to the vector, and less about the generating of unique values, as the question does not actually state that the random indexes must be unique